# JavaScript the Good Parts: unshift function

Tags: javascript

I'm reading JavaScript:The Good Parts by Crockford and I'm having trouble understanding the reimplementation of the `unshift` method that he does in his book.Here is the the code:

```
Array.method('unshift', function ( ) {
  this.splice.apply(this,
    [0, 0].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)));
  return this.length;
});
```

It would be useful if someone could go through what is happening step by step. One of the things that I don't understand is why he concatenates [0 , 0] to the result of the `Array.prototype.slice`.

Comment: lol, I can see what he's doing, and if no one breaks this down before I get a chance, I'll tell you. but ... how old is this book you're reading? unshift is already and Array method in JS and has been since 1.2. I'm not sure I see the point in breaking down library code? just curious

Comment: The author knows it is a method already. He just re implements it to show the reader how it works.

Comment: ah, i see. Then why doesn't he explain it. lol. looks like an answer popped already that is spot on. if you need further info, look up `.apply` which will explain why the first param is `this`.

Comment: Yeah he should have explained it , but didn't....

Comment: [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) | [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) | [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why he concatenates [0 , 0] to the result of the Array.prototype.slice

The first two arguments of `splice` (which is where the resulting array is applied to) are:

- `index` which is `0` because you are adding to the front of the array
- `howMany` (to remove) which is `0` because you are just adding new elements

The remaining arguments are the values to be added to the front of the array, which are taken from `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)` (to convert the data into the `arguments` object into data in an array).